# Is the pan_tilt_node functional?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to run:
$ rostopic pub /pan_tilt_node/pan_tilt_cmd pan_tilt_node/PanTiltCmd --once 90 90
$ rostopic pub /pan_tilt_node/pan_tilt_cmd pan_tilt_node/PanTiltCmd --once 45 45

#1
But it only functions once on the first pub command.  Alternating values of the pan and tilt do not create any additional movement, although the node reports the parameters.

#2
If I try to do both pan and tilt to - 90
--once -- -90 -- -90
I get a parameter error "--".

Example from:
http://pharos.ece.utexas.edu/wiki/index.php/How_to_Control_the_Lynx_Motion_Pan-Tilt_Assembly_from_ROS

Thanks,
Alan KM6VV

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56774/is-the-pan_tilt_node-functional?/) by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 191 on 2013-03-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) on 2013-03-02**:
All working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All working!  Digital servos limited range so there was no response.

---

Originally posted by [KM6VV](https://answers.ros.org/users/3088/km6vv/) with karma: 191 on 2013-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1